# Ruby system call not observing path for python scripts

Tags: python, ruby, windows, cmd, system

This works:

```
system "python \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/someScript.py\"
```

This doesn't work:

```
system "python \"someScript.py\"
```

The directory containing `someScript.py` is added to my windows `PATH` variable, so if I open a CMD window and type:

```
someScript.py
```

it runs fine.

How do I make is so that my ruby script is able to call `someScript.py` while observing the windows environment path variable so I don't have to specify an absolute path for the python script?

Comment: You can change the current directory in ruby with [Dir.chdir "some-path"](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-chdir)

Answer (score 0):

Python *does not* use the `$PATH` environment variable.

You always have to specify a full path to the python script on the command line. This can be relative from the current directory or an absolute path.

The association between files with the `.py` extension and the Python executable is a [separate registration](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable), where Windows executes the Python executable after the script file has been located on the current search path. Windows passes the full, absolute path of the script to the Python executable when it invokes it. When you execute the Python executable directly using `system` you bypass that lookup.

You *could* try to execute the Python script directly using `system "someScript.py"` *without* the `python` executable, but I am not familiar enough with Ruby and Windows to know if that'll honour the `.py` extension registration used by the Windows command prompt.

Comment: @sr2222: That is something different altogether, that's for looking up modules when importing. The OP is looking for ways to specify what main script needs to be loaded by the Python interpreter. `PYTHONPATH` is not consulted for that either.